# solidity expected primary expression error

Tags: javascript, html, solidity

This is the method:

```
 function insert(AddressSet storage set_, uint256 index_, address valueToInsert_ ) internal returns ( bool ) {
    return _insert( set_._inner, index_, bytes32(bytes20(, uint256(valueToInsert_)))); //error is in this line                                   
  }
```

Comment: The question is incomprehensible. Some tips to improve it:

1. You do not state the version of solidity that is a must since there are enormous differences among them.

2. Code is not formatted and difficult to read.

3. In general, read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile your code, you should create a struct data type that only contains a uint.

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.4.24/frequently-asked-questions.html